# Grab id from another model and then save it into a new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

Really trying to get my head around the following situation. I am grabbing football results via a screen scrape and saving them to a model (result), ok so far.... I  have some associations setup between models and I want to grab all the ids from an associated model and save into my result model.. My models are setup as so

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_team, :fixture_date, :home_team, :kickoff_time, :prediction_id
end

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team, :fixture_id, :home_score, :home_team, :score

  has_one :fixture
  has_one :result
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team, :fixture_date, :home_score, :home_team,  :prediction_id
end
```

My screen scrape looks like so

```
def get_results 
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
 days = doc.css('.table-header').each do |h2_tag|
  date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
   matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
   matches.each do |match|
  home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
  away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
  score = match.css('.score').text.strip
  home_score, away_score = score.split("-").map(&:to_i)
  Result.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, score: score, fixture_date: date, home_score: home_score, away_score: away_score)

  end
 end
end
```

So before i create my result i need to get the prediction id's from the fixture model that correspond to the correct result (football match) and then save them at the same time as when i save all the other attributes..I hope that makes sense..

Thanks

EDIT

ok so to i have got this far

```
fixture = Fixture.where(fixture_date: date, home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team).first
prediction_array = Prediction.where(fixture_id: fixture.id)
```

need to pull out the values then..

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have a prediction id in your fixture model, which means each fixture can only have one prediction.

Also, a couple of the attributes are redundant - if a prediction references a fixture then it doesn't need to store it's own information on the teams.

I would suggest removing the results model and altering the other two models to the following:

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_team, :fixture_date, :home_team, :kickoff_time, :home_score, :away_score

  has_many :predictions
  has_many :correct_predictions, class_name: "Prediction", foreign_key: "fixture_id", conditions: proc{["home_score = #{self.home_score} AND away_score = #{self.away_score}"]}
end

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fixture_id, :home_score, :away_score

  belongs_to :fixture
end
```

Now instead of creating a result entry, just find the fixture with `Fixture.where(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date)` and set the two scores.

`correct_predictions` is an association with a condition, so once your fixture has scores filled in you can call `my_fixture.correct_predictions` to get all of the correct predictions (you might need to change the condition depending on your database adapter).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have got it working but now its time to refactor and bring in the has_many association so a fixture can have many predictions..so will take your advice and see how i go

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this may be the wrong way to do it but i have managed to get this to work, the final code looks like this

```
 def get_results # Get me all results
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
  days = doc.css('.table-header').each do |h2_tag|
  date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
  matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
    matches.each do |match|
     home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
     away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
     score = match.css('.score').text.strip
     home_score, away_score = score.split("-").map(&:to_i)
     fixture = Fixture.where(fixture_date: date, home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team).first
     prediction_array = Prediction.where(fixture_id: fixture)

     pred = prediction_array.map {|p| p.id}
      pred.each do |p|
      pred_id = p
      Result.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date, home_score: home_score, away_score: away_score, prediction_id: pred_id)
     end
   end
 end
end
```

What i added was this

```
 fixture = Fixture.where(fixture_date: date, home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team).first
     prediction_array = Prediction.where(fixture_id: fixture)

     pred = prediction_array.map {|p| p.id}
      pred.each do |p|
      pred_id = p
```

So get all the fixtures which matched date, home_team, away_team from the results being grabbed. Then get all the predictions where the fixture_id matched the id's of what received by fixture.

Then map them out, iterate through them and assigned its value to pred_id

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Prediction belongs_to Fixture association, you could do: `fixture.prediction`

Comment: I meant you could use one ;)